# portable AIR apps. Is that possible?

Tags: air, portability

is it possible to build a portable version of an air app? So that it's possible to put it on flash, and launch on any PC.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite possible. The only thing the developer(s) need to keep in mind is not to store anything in app-storage:// of the application. They should ask the user before storing any data from the user. Similarly, when referencing files the developers should try and put the same in the app:/ folder. Lastly, encrypted local storage should not be used.

If these guidelines are followed, an AIR application should easily work from a flash drive as well.

Comment: I have a closed application that works on the same principle and is quite portable on the Flash drive - saving data to the same flash drive from where the application was launched. May be I will try and create a simple demo for the same.

Answer (score 3):

In AIR 3, you can package the app as a captive runtime bundle. This is self contained and can be run without a special install. (A few features that require registry settings on windows won't work, like registering to handle file types.)

Comment: Even with captive runtime, one might not be able to port the application workflows. What we only achieve with that, is installation/execution of application without the need for AIR runtime to be pre-installed.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect not. Adobe AIR makes extensive use of directories in the logged-in user's profile for things like local storage. I believe that that is also where it sets up the verification for the code-signing certificate. So it would likely not be possible for you to run an AIR application portably from a flash drive.

I am going to guess you have tried it. If not, then give it a try. Install the Application using one machine, and when prompted for the install location, sent it to a Flash drive. Then take that Flash drive to another machine that has AIR installed and try running it from there. See what happens, and see what kind of error you get. Like I said, I suspect it will not work.